# Замена слову sophisticated или понятию "обладающий многими функциями"

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы, заимствования, переводы

Я ищу слово, которое бы могло заменить одно из значений английского слова *sophisticated*:

> **sophisticated** (of a machine, system, or technique) — developed to a high degree of complexity.
>
> *highly sophisticated computer systems*

Мой пример:

> ... и конечно, тебе потребуется «умный» файловый менеджер или какой-то скрипт, или и то и другое.

Пока что я использую слово *умный*, взяв его в кавычки, но такой вариант меня не очень-то устраивает; от кавычек хотелось бы избавиться, потому что в моем документе и так имеется их избыточное, на мой взгляд, употребление.

*(Обновлено)* Иными словами, мне нужен синоним для понятия *обладающий многими функциями*. Но при этом слово *многофункциональный* не считаю полностью подходящим.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос оригинальный английский текст, который переводите. И, желательно, не одно предложение, а весь параграф, чтобы контекст был понятен.

Comment: Предложу "продвинутый". Но не видя ни оригинала, ни общего стиля вашего перевода, советовать сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй ответ

**Сложный файловый менеджер?**  Этот вариант был принят, но мне он кажется **наименее удачным** и вряд ли может заменить слово «умный», а ведь именно так ставился вопрос.

Согласно толковому словарю  у слова «сложный» **пять значений**, и все они значительно отличаются друг от друга. Сложный – это слишком о**бщее  и неоднозначное** название, оно не дает представления  о конкретном значении слова, нужна расшифровка.  Сложный в эксплуатации – это плохо,  имеющий много функций – это хорошо. При переводе нужно задумываться о значении  именно русских слов, о **соответствии** смысла в двух языках.

У нас даже про компьютер скорее скажут, что он не сложный, а более мощный (современный, производительный). А что такое сложный файловый менеджер – может быть, с ним **сложно** и неудобно работать?  Или у него более **высокая степень сложности**?

В английском языке это, может быть, и понятно, но по-русски лучше сказать, что он ***умный, интеллектуальный***, если необходимо передать смысл именно  **одним словом.**  Тогда  будет ясно, что речь идет о файловом менеджере,  более разнообразном по своим функциям и возможностям,  более соответствующем решаемым задачам. Ничего этого, как я думаю, **не передаст слово «сложный».**

Comment: Если слово многозначное, это не значит что нужно его избегать и использовать другое по смыслу. Умный, интеллектуальный — значит обладающий способностью мыслить в переносном смысле. По-английски умный smart, умный поиск smart search. И он так называется, потому что он не тупо ищет совпадения, а определённым образом как бы думает, например предлагает подсказки. Файловый менеджер не думает, а просто выполняет команды пользователя.

Comment: А умный дом, интеллектуальный продукт – они тоже мыслят и занимаются умным поиском? Это  действительно переносное значение слов, но именно в русском языке, на него и надо ориентироваться.  Соответствие смысла в двух языках – вот что главное при переводе, а не только соответствие слов. https://studbooks.net/1560514/marketing/intellktualnyy_produkt_klassifikatsiya
К тому же все сказанное мною уже было обозначено в теме, в том числе и автором вопроса: «Слово сложный, мне кажется, ассоциируется в первую очередь со сложностью использования или освоения».

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю, что "обладающий многими функциями" верно отражает здесь смысл эпитета sophistiсated. Речь может идти и о *единственной* функции, для осуществления которой наилучшим образом применены **изысканные технические средства** (по существу, это либо *усложнения* с применением известных средств, либо "инновации", т. е. изобретательский подход, что тоже сложно, но в *интеллектуальном* смысле). Попытки обойтись одним словом приводят в таких случаях к жаргонизму "*продвинутый*" (интеллектуальный, изысканный, утонченный). Более формально в некоторых контекстах (не к файловому менеджеру, конечно) может подойти "*компьютеры повышенной сложности*" и т. п.

Comment: _Не думаю, что "обладающий многими функциями" верно отражает здесь смысл эпитета sophistiсated_ - Да, по прошествию дня тоже так думаю. _Попытки обойтись одним словом_ - Не обязательно одним, можно несколькими.

Comment: Возможно, наилучшим вариантом будет _интеллектуальный_, который вы привели.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых «sophisticated» — это вовсе не обладающий многими функциями, а просто очень сложный.

Определение, которое вы привели правильное:

> sophisticated (of a machine, system, or technique) — developed
> to a high degree of complexity.
>
> Если перевести: (о машине, системе или технике) — развитый до высокой
> степени сложности.

Про множество функций вообще ничего не говорится. У объекта может быть одна функция, но для её реализации может быть задействован сложный механизм.

Светофор может быть просто устроен, и зажигать красный, жёлтый, зелёный, просто через определённые промежутки времени, а может быть сложным, и учитывать загруженость дороги, с какой стороны большая пробка; светофоры могут быть объединены в систему, и учитывать, какой свет горит на других перекрёстках, чтоб машины как можно реже останавливались на пути. Это сложная система, но у неё по сути одна функция — зажигать свет, разрешающий или запрещающий проезд.

Можно сказать: сложно (технически) устроенный, навороченный, хитроумный, высокотехнологичный.

На мой взгляд в оригинале, слово «sophisticated», возможно не совсем к месту употреблено, но если  смотреть по смыслу предложения, то правильный перевод в данном случае, это просто сложный или очень сложный, что вполне соответствует слову «sophisticated».

Ожегов:

> сло́жный — 1. Состоящий из нескольких частей, многообразный по составу
> частей и связей между ними. *Сложные вещества. **Механизм сложного
> устройства**.*

Ещё есть в Словаре русского языка Евгеньевой:

> сло́жный 3. Затейливый, замысловатый по строению, форме. Сложный
> орнамент. *Колена танца становятся все сложнее и замысловатее.*
> Куприн, Гамбринус.

Слово сложный вполне подходит: «тебе потребуется сложный файловый менеджер».

Например, проводник Windows можно считать простым файловым менеджером, а Total Commander — сложным.

Comment: Слово _сложный_, мне кажется, ассоциируется в первую очередь со сложностью использования или освоения. Возможно, как я секундой до вашего ответа написал в комментарии к ответу Alex_ander, более подходящим вариантоом будет _интеллектуальный_. Оно уже имеет нужный технический оттенок. Например, часто можно услышать что-то вроде "интеллектуальный поиск".

Comment: @jsv Слово сложный имеет несколько значений, в том числе «представляющий затруднения для понимания, решения, осуществления и т. п.» (словарь Евгеньевной). И это не основное значение, потому что сложный, это от слова складывать, как бы сложенный из нескольких частей. Я вам привёл примеры из словарей, где у «сложный», есть подходящие значения. Не нужно накладывать своё понимание слова на смысл. Или вы считаете, что «сложный» имеет негативную коннотацию, что может отпугнуть читателя?

Comment: @jsv «интеллектуальный» — это обладающий интеллектом (мыслительной способностью) в переносном смысле. Интеллектуальный поиск не просто ищет тупо совпадения, а как бы думает: исправляет ошибки, предлагает варианты запроса, ищет не только по заданному слову, но и по синонимам и т. п.

Comment: @jsv У вас цель что-то кому-то продать? Складывается впечатление, что вы пытаетесь избежать слов с негативной коннотацией и подобрать с позитивной, чтоб сохранить мотивацию человека. Если это технический перевод, он должен быть точным. Если это реклама, то, конечно надо думать о коннотациях слов. Но «интеллектуальный» тут вообще не в тему.

Comment: Eagle, нет цели продать. Есть, как вы выразились, цель добиться точности, но при этом избежать использования слов, точность которых будет исключительно словарной. Это как в общении между людьми. Есть люди, которые, при малейшем несоответствии истины, как они ее видят, используют слово "ложь". Юридически, технически они правы, но это выглядит агрессивно и неуместно. Я не говорю, что ваш ответ плохой. Пока что рассматриваю слово "сложный" как один из вариантов, за ваш ответ проголосовал.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если посмотреть **частотность** перевода слова, то чаще всего оно переводится как **«сложный»,** но это по отношению **к технике.** Например:

Computers are here to stay and they'll become **more and more sophisticated,** but we have to remember they are just tools.  – Компьютеры останутся здесь, и они будут становиться все более и более сложными, но мы должны помнить, что они всего лишь инструменты.

Even small provincial schools are buying **sophisticated** software for their computer rooms.  – Даже небольшие провинциальные школы покупают сложное программное обеспечение для своих компьютерных классов.

2. К слову «умный ближе всего **«интеллектуальный»**, например:
   В Индии экспорт программного продукта в 2007 г. достиг 50 млрд. долл. и стал сравнимым с затратами на закупку нефти: так в экономике **интеллектуальный продукт** становится самым ценным. [С. П. Капица. Парадоксы роста. Законы развития человечества (2010)]
3. Пока в словаре не отмечается  такое значение слова «интеллектуальный», но оно используется без кавычек  со значением **«имеющий отношение к интеллекту».**
4. Можно также предложить слово «высокоинтеллектуальный».

... *и конечно, тебе потребуется **высокоинтеллектуальный файловый менеджер** или какой-то скрипт, или и то и другое.*

**Интеллект**,  м. [лат. intellectus  – понятие, рассудок]  Мыслительные способности человека, разум, уровень умственного развития. Быть равным кому-л. по интеллекту.

**Интеллектуальный,**  Умственный, духовный. И-ые способности. И-ая жизнь. // С высокоразвитым интеллектом; мыслящий. И. человек. Петров-Водкин - и. художник

**Высокоинтеллектуальный**  1. Отличающийся высоким интеллектом. 2. Рассчитанный на таких людей. В-ая проза. В. фильм.

Comment: Хорошей идеей было посмотреть частотность переводов слова, так сказать, перенять опыт других в этом вопросе. По словарю сложно оценить, насколько часто, и в каких случаях используется определённый перевод.

Answer (score 1):

Качественным определением для «файлового менеджера» могут послужить следующие слова - кандидаты: нестандартный, усовершенствованный, улучшенный, продуманный, коррегированный,  полифункциональный, расширенный, развитой / утонченный, sophisticated,  изощренный, мудреный, матерый, прокачанный, заточенный.
Все слова расставлены в порядке убывания степени их соответствия.
Слова, помещенные за знаком «/», в технических текстах использовать не стоит.